# Regex Range of numbers or just a number

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I had a request for a textbox to have a range of values which I was using the pattern `^(\d{1,3})\-(\d{1,3})$` and that seemed to work.

In **addition** now they want: 
A positive 2 digit number limited from `0 to 20`
**OR** 
A positive 2 digit range `(01-20 or 1-3 or 1-03 or 01-4 and so on)`

I am using `^\d{2}([\-]\d{2})?$` but I am unclear on how to impose a limit of 0 to 20

Using C# ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pattern1 `^(20|[10]?\d)$` can match 0-20

pattern2 `^(20|[10]?\d)(?:-(20|[10]?\d))?$` can match "0-20", "1-20", "2-20"..."20-20" or 0 to 20

But the bad news is pattern2 will match string like "5-1", "20-3"

For this problem, the silver bullet does not exist, you need to write some code to check range(get strings from group 1 and group 2, convert them to integer for compare).

Comment: This worked whenI combined the process into two regex expressions. I used the second one on the RegularExpressionValidator itself which gave the desired result.

Comment: if I need a regex that would match age from 18 to 75?

Answer (score 0):

For the limit of 20 you'll have to do the digits separately. Make sure it's either 20 or the first digit is 0-1, and the second is 0-9.

i.e. `20 | ([0-1]?[0-9])`

Edit: So the whole thing should be `^\d{2}([-](20 | ([0-1]?[0-9])))?$`.

Comment: This accepts `29`... you'd probably want something like `([01]?\d|2\d)`.

Comment: Good catch. I think what I did should fix it.

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to ensure the first number isn't higher than the second, you should probably change the first part of your regex. `\d{2}` accepts all digits up to 99. Maybe something like this: `/^([01]?[0-9]|20)-([01]?[0-9]|20)$/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ([01]?\d|2\d).

That might do what you are looking for.